# Paypal iOS always returning same paypal id

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

we are developing and app that allows the user to add user credit by paypal. In order to do that in iOS we do:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    float value = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:self.tfBalance.text] floatValue];
    value = value * 1.04;
    // Create a PayPalPayment
    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];

    // Amount, currency, and description
    payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value]];
    payment.currencyCode = @"EUR";
    payment.shortDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Añadir Saldo: %@+4%% comisión PayPal", self.tfBalance.text];


    payment.intent = PayPalPaymentIntentSale;
    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
    paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                   configuration:self.payPalConfiguration
                                                                        delegate:self];

    // Present the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And the delegate:

```
#pragma mark - PayPal delegate
- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController
             didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
// Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment.
[self verifyCompletedPayment:completedPayment];

// Dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
// The payment was canceled; dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)verifyCompletedPayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
// Verificamos en el servidor si se ha realizado el pago
NSDictionary* response = [completedPayment.confirmation objectForKey:@"response"];
NSString* paypalId = [response objectForKey:@"id"];
[[MMApplicationModel sharedInstance].restManager createPayPalOperation:paypalId amount:[completedPayment.amount stringValue] completionHandler:^(bool verified) {
    if(verified){
        [self.tfBalance setText:@""];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(refreshBalance) withObject:nil];
    }
    else{
        //Mostramos el error
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [self showMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"topup_error_creating_operation", nil) withTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"error", nil) andTag:0];
    }
}];
}
```

The thing is that in PayPal SDK documentation, they say:

> After a successful payment is made with the MSDK 2.x, the MSDK returns data to your app about the payment (received by the MSDK from the REST API).

```
{
"client": {
"environment": "sandbox",
"paypal_sdk_version": "2.0.0",
"platform": "iOS",
"product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK;"
},
"response": {
"create_time": "2014-02-12T22:29:49Z",
"id": "PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI",
"intent": "sale",
"state": "approved"
},
"response_type": "payment"
}
```

> You server can store the unique payment id value from the above response.

As the paypal id is the identifier to check the paypal operation in the server. But PayPal-SDK for iOS is always returning same id (in Android is working well) so I don't know if it is a sandbox issue or I am doing something wrong.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the library you are using is quite old 2.0.0, so it the creation time. Have you tried reproducing this behavior with latest PayPal SDK https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases/tag/2.6.1 ?

Comment: The response you see is from PayPal docs, we are using 2.6.1 from cocoapods.

Comment: i suggest you open the issue with the actual response here https://github.com/paypal/paypal-ios-sdk/issues so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Perfect @Romk1n we'll do it

Comment: you probably running in Mock, but without the output we cannot verify.

Comment: Thanks @Romk1n, it was indeed a silly question. If you post the answer I'll give you the correct answer.